# Powershell console causing script failures

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

Got a crazy one that's come out of left field.

We have a PDF file that gets generated by a vendor application that needs to be split. I'm using iTextSharp.DLL and it's working great, but only in the Powershell ISE. When I try running the same script via the Console it breaks.

Here is a cut down portion of the script

```
Add-Type -Path ("MyDrive:\MyPath\itextsharp.dll");
$pdf = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader($sourcePDFFile);
[iTextsharp.text.Document]$sourcePDF = $pdf.GetPageSizeWithRotation($fromPage);
$sourcePDF.Open();
```

When I run this in Powershell ISE I get

```
2016-11-15T19:17:48 Runnning in Windows PowerShell ISE Host as MYDOMAIN\myuser
2016-11-15T19:17:48 Opening PDF file
2016-11-15T19:17:50 Outputting seperated PDF files
2016-11-15T19:17:51 1 file(s) processed out of 3
```

When I run this in Powershell Console I get

```
2016-11-15T19:20:19 Runnning in ConsoleHost as MYDOMAIN\myuser
2016-11-15T19:20:19 Opening PDF file
2016-11-15T19:20:21 Outputting seperated PDF files
2016-11-15T19:20:21 —- Exception Message: 
ErrorRecord  : Method invocation failed because [iTextSharp.text.Rectangle] does not contain a method named 'Open'.
```

If I output the results of Get-Member on the $sourcePDF variable, the type shows as iTextsharp.text.Document when running in ISE, but iTextSharp.text.Rectangle when running via console.

Hoping someone can given me some pointers on what's causing the problem and how I can resolve it.

Cheers
Phil

Comment: Unlikely but perhaps you are loading different dll's. It's worth verifying though.

Comment: Also worth verifying is the type of the `$pdf` variable. I can imagine that already being different.

Comment: I think along the same vein as Lieven, are you running different shell architectures in your examples above?

Comment: Script is loading the same DLL as I've put it in the same folder as the script

Have since tried running in 32bit ISE and Console, but this produces the same result. Works in ISE, fails in Console.
The $pdf variable is the PdfReader type that it's created with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your ideas. I've resolved this issue by changing how the variable is created.

`$sourcePDF = New-Object iTextsharp.text.Document;`

instead of

`[iTextsharp.text.Document]$sourcePDF = $pdf.GetPageSizeWithRotation($fromPage);`

Turns out the $pdf.Get... is not required to create new PDFs.

Cheers
Phil

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is the problem: PowerShell ISE runs in a different apartment state. The ISE runs in STA. The console however runs in MTA (depending on the version).

You can check the apartment state with:

```
$host.Runspace.ApartmentState
```

or

```
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.GetApartmentState()
```

To force the PowerShell console to start in STA mode use:

```
powershell.exe -sta
```

Comment: Seems the apartment model is the same

`2016-11-16T08:28:38 Runnning in ConsoleHost as MYDOMAIN\myuser`
`2016-11-16T08:28:38 Current in apartment state STA`

`2016-11-16T08:24:42 Runnning in Windows PowerShell ISE Host as MYDOMAIN\myuser`
`2016-11-16T08:24:42 Current in apartment state STA`